# How to add play button inside responsive slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, responsive-slides

I have a set of images to display using a responsive slide. I found a link to create responsive slide: http://responsiveslides.com. I don't know to add pause/play button inside the slide. My code is as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
  <script>

      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        pauseControls:true,
        nav: true,
        pause: false,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <a class="pause_slider" href="#">Pause Slider</a>
      <a class="play_slider" href="#">Play Slider</a>


    <div class="callbacks_container">
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
        <li>
          <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="caption">This is a caption</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="caption">This is another caption</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="caption">The third caption</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The above is the source code. How can I add pause and play button into my slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use another plug-in.  [wow slider](http://see%20:%20http://wowslider.com/demos.html) You will get by default pause and play buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Do you necessarily have to use that library or can you listen to another option?

I recommend you [swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper). It is a better library in my opinion. Here is the [get-started link](https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/).

In this example you can change the value of the boolean `autoplay` with methods `start()` (to autoplay the slider) and `stop()` (to pause it).

Here you have an example. Hope it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  speed: 600,
  spaceBetween: 90,
  autoplay: true,
  disableOnInteraction: true,
  loop: true
 });
 const mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
 let isSliderActive = true;

 $("#slider-control").click(function() {
  if (isSliderActive) {
   mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
   isSliderActive = false;
   this.innerHTML = 'PLAY';
   console.log('slider stopped');
  } else {
   mySwiper.autoplay.start();
   isSliderActive = true;
   this.innerHTML = 'PAUSE';
   console.log('slider activated');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
 .swiper-slide { text-align: center; }
</style>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  <div>Slide 1</div>
 </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  <div>Slide 2</div>
 </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  <div>Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="slider-control">PAUSE</button>
```

Comment: thank you @Nico Diz , But how to add previous and next button  here

Comment: According to the guide (https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/), you should add in the HTML:

<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div><div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

And in the JS, inside the new Swiper block, add the folowong prop:

navigation: {
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
}